# What is a Binary Literal?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, binary-data

Can someone give a clear explanation of what Binary Literal is? What is the difference between binary literals, hexadecimal and binary numbers, strings? What are they used for?

Comment: Literals: http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html. A binary literal would most likely be a string of the form "0b11011011".

Answer (score 2):

They're used for expressing a number using bits.

```
0b0010010101001
```

Answer (score 2):

Because sometimes it's easier to convey the intent of a value in binary.  This applies to base 16 as well.  They're all numbers when it comes down to it, but if I want to assign a flag with multiple bits set, something like this seems clearer than the alternative(s).

```
flags = 0b110101
```

Comment: Even that may be less clear (though far less verbose) than using a bitwise-OR of named flag constants. :-)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Oh it certainly would be.  I can't think of a lot of uses for binary literals in practice... this is what I cam up with :)

Comment: It's a great example and I'll give you +1. I was just providing some color commentary :-)

Answer (score 1):

Literals: http://cpp.comsci.us/etymology/literals.html.

> Literal constants (often referred to as literals or constants) are
>   invariants whose values are implied by their representations

Just as a hexadecimal literal is a string of the form "0xABCD", a binary literal is a string of the form "0b11011011".  They can be distinguished from each other by checking the first two characters.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html